# Charaterize the $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ a sigma algebra for the stopping time $\tau$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Consider a stochastic process $X: [0, \infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$

We define
$\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(X(s), 0 \leq s \leq t)$ The sigma algebra generated by the sets $\{\omega: X(s,\omega) \in \Gamma \}$ for $\Gamma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Now a stopping time is a function $\tau: \Omega \to [0,\infty] $ such that $[\tau \leq t]=\{\omega:\tau(\omega) \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t $ for all $t$.

Let $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(X(s), 0 \leq s <\infty)$.
We consider now the sigma algebra given by
$$\mathcal{F}_\tau = \{A \in \mathcal{F}: A \cap [\tau \leq t] \in \mathcal{F}_t , \forall t \}.$$

We would like to prove that
$$\mathcal{F}_\tau = \sigma (X(s \wedge \tau): 0 \leq s < \infty )$$

It is clear  that $$\sigma (X(s \wedge \tau): 0 \leq s < \infty ) \subset \{A \in \mathcal{F}: A \cap [\tau \leq t] \in \mathcal{F}_t , \forall t \}$$

but to the other inclusion I am trying to follow Stroock and Varadhan
(Diffusion processes with continuous coefficients I -  1969 - appendix - pg 394) they say that:

**Claim**  if $\xi $ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ measurable then there is a measurable function $f: (\mathbb{R}^d)^{\infty} \to \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence $t_1 < \ldots <t_n <\ldots$ such that $$\xi(\omega) = f(X(t_1,\omega),\ldots,X(t_n,\omega), \ldots).$$

The question is to show the above claim.

**Edit:** Just to give the originals here below:

In pg 394 of  Diffusion processes with continuous coefficients I one reads
[image]

but in Dynkin we read

[image]

It is not clear we can use Dynkin 1.5 since we don't know that $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ is generated by a family of times $t \ in T$ that index it as in  Dynkin's case